# Awesomplete filter - only beginning of words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using awesomplete plugin.
I want to make a filter that only matches the beginning of words.
So I have some strings in my array:
 
"Hi, I'm a crappy programmer".
"Yep, you're worse than my grandfather!"

Now, when I type in "gra" in the search field, I only want it to match with the second string, where the word "grandfather" starts with "gra", and not "proGRAmmer" from the first string with the "gra" in the middle.

Any help on how to put this with awesomplete?
I tried with at filter:

```
_.FILTER_WORDSTART = function(text, input) {
    return RegExp("\b" + $.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

$.regExpEscape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

... but that doesn't match me with anything. If I replace the "\b" with "^" it will match only the first word in the whole string, and if I replace with " ", it will match only beginning of words, but NOT the first words in the string.

Help please!

Comment: Use `"\\b"` as `"\b"` is a *backspace*.

Comment: Use `return new RegExp("\\b" + $.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);`

Comment: That was awesome! Problem fixed in less than 3 minutes, thanks man!! :D
And sorry for the dup...